# Most efficient command to search the first line of many files (windows)

Tags: windows, command-line, search, findstr

I am new to the windows ecosystem.  I have been tasked with writing a program that will search several 10's (maybe even 100's) of thousands of files for a particular string.  The string that must be matched is a serial number consisting of only numbers and letters and is less than 20 characters.  Right now, my program is executing the following command:

```
findstr /i /m /s "searchStr" "C:\Directory\To\Search\*.*"
```

The above command works, however, it is too slow.  The file(s) which could contain a particular serial number will only have the serial number in their first line.

Does anybody know of an efficient way to recursively search a directory for all files that contain a particular string only in the first line?

Comment: If you use a Windows implementation of the Unix `sed` utility, the following command should work efficiently: `sed -sn '1s/searchStr/&/p' SearchPath\*.*`. Unfortunately it will show you the serial string, but not the file names. To show the file names, you will to use a `for` loop which checks for output from the current file and shows its name if so. But before you do all that, check that the direct call is fast enough.

Comment: So all your program does is invoke findstr? Reading your description it seemed as if you're supposed to write your own text search code.

Comment: I was trying to see what tools I could use to aid in the search.  I could parse each file myself, but I thought a built-in "tried and true" program may be more efficient then what I come up with.  But maybe not...

Answer (score 2):

In PowerShell (v3.0+), maybe...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path x:\pathto\*.log `
| ForEach-Object {
    if (Get-Content -LiteralPath $_ -First 1 `
        | Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern 'serialnumber') 
    {
        Write-Output $_
    }
}
```

Different parameters to `Get-ChildItem` can recurse subfolders, etc; to `Get-Content` can obtain more or less content from the file; and to `Select-String` can perform more-complex matches (regex, case-sensitive, etc).

Comment: Nice answer that showcases some of Powershell's capabilities; I thought I'd add links to the current documentation for [`Get-ChildItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem), [`Get-Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) and [`Select-String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string).

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest a few options if you don't need to use `findstr`, but first of all you should see whether you can restrict the search to files of a certain filetype, as that is sure to speed things up.

1. [FileLocator Lite](https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite) is in my experience faster at finding files and checking their contents. Be sure to fill in both the "filename" (if applicable) and "contained text" fields, as well as the starting directory.
2. `ag -il "searchStr"`: [ag](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/the-silver-searcher-for-windows.html) is built for speed so it should give you results, fast. Be sure to restrict the search by filetype if you can, although binary files are skipped by default already. Also available under [Cygwin](https://cygwin.org).
3. `find -exec awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1} NR==1 && /searchStr/ {print FILENAME": "$0}' {} \;` Try this if you have Cygwin or another POSIX-like environment available, in order to check out your idea about searching only the first line. Combine `find` to get the filenames (and hopefully also filter them) and `awk` to check the first line and print it together with the filename.
4. `find | parallel 'perl -lane '\'' print "$ARGV: $_" if $. == 1 and /searchStr/i '\'' {}'` Another idea to try and speed things up is putting available cores and threads to work: that's what [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel) is for. This example sports `perl`, but it does the same as `awk` in `3.` above. Here's a command breakdown:

   `find` look for files in the current directory and its subdirectories. You can specify a different directory to look in and a file pattern or extension to filter on: `find /cygdrive/c/Directory/To/Search -iname "*.txt"`.

   `|` "pipe", i.e. feed the list of results to the next command.

   `parallel` execute the next command in parallel.

   `perl` scripting language that excels at text file manipulation, can replace `sed` or `awk`.

   `-lane` useful set of switches for perl one-liners.

   `'\''` escaped apostrophe, needed since we already opened an apostrophe set after `parallel`.

   `print "$ARGV: $_"` print the filename (`$ARGV`), a colon, a space and the full line (`$_`).

   `if` only execute the previous instruction if the following condition(s) are met.

   `$. == 1` line number (`$.`) is equal to one (`1`), i.e. we are looking at the first line of the file.

   `and` the following condition must be met, too.

   `/searchStr/i` the line being examined contains the text `searchStr`, case-insensitively.

   `'\''` another escaped apostrophe marks the end of the `perl` instruction.

   `{}` this is going to be substituted by `parallel` with each of the filenames passed on by `find`.

   `'` end of the `parallel` instruction.

**Update:** Both `awk` and `perl` read the whole file even if actions are bound to the first line only. The solution is to explicitly stop elaboration at line 2:

`find -exec awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE=1} NR > 1 {exit} /searchStr/ {print FILENAME": "$0}' {} \;`
`find | parallel 'perl -lape '\'' exit if $. == 2; print "$ARGV: $_" if /searchStr/i '\'' {}'`